# How to restrict the format of weights in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

In Keras (tensorflow backend) the weights and biases of a neural network are float32 by default. Is there a way to change that and provide a different format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in `~/.keras/keras.json`:

```
{
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "epsilon": 1e-07
}
```

You can change the `floatx` to change the default floating point format. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/backend/):

> floatx: String, "float16", "float32", or "float64". Default float precision.